# check PSQL extension unaccent with PHP

Tags: php, psql

I want to write code in PHP which check if PSQL extension unaccent is installed in DB. If is installed, then must show message Success, other way message Failed.
At the moment I don't have any idea how to do that, maybe someone have tried that before and can share me some ideas.

**edited**
it's not duplicate of topic where someone asked how to check "PHP" extension. I ask for help to check if "PSQL" extension which must be installed for each DB, is installed.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie that topic is about php extension... I need to check PSQL extension... its not the same way how to find it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, then I misunderstood. As I understand it, installed extensions are present in the pg_extension table, so do a `select * from pg_extension` and check if the extension you're looking for is in the result?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I was thinking about that, though maybe some have already working code or other way. Want something simple.